# Register-ObjectEvent to async uploading a file using System.Net.WebClient stops working if i'm use System.Windows.Forms in a powershell script

Tags: powershell, winforms, asynchronous, events, runspace

I want to download files from the Internet on the Form and display the download progress in the ProgressBar. To do this I subscribe to loading events and do asynchronous loading. Everything is working. Here is the simplified code (removed all unnecessary):

```
Add-Type -assembly System.Windows.Forms

$isDownloaded = $False
$webMain = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $webMain -EventName 'DownloadFileCompleted' -SourceIdentifier WebMainDownloadFileCompleted -Action {    
    $Global:isDownloaded = $True
}

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $webMain -EventName 'DownloadProgressChanged' -SourceIdentifier WebMainDownloadProgressChanged -Action {
    $Global:Data = $event
}

function DownloadFile($Link, $Path, $Name) {

    write-host "begin"

    $Global:webMain.DownloadFileAsync($Link, $Path)
    
    While (!$isDownloaded) {
        $percent = $Global:Data.SourceArgs.ProgressPercentage
        If ($percent -ne $null) {
            write-host $percent
        }
        Wait-Event -Timeout 1
    }

    write-host "end"
}

DownloadFile 'https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2301-x64.exe' 'D:\7Zip.exe' '7Zip'
```

Everything is working. Now I add it anywhere in the code

`$Form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form`

or

`$Button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button`

and the script doesn't work. The DownloadProgressChanged and DownloadFileCompleted events do not occur at all.

Question: Why does just creating a Form or Button interfere with the script?

Without System.Windows.Forms.Form the code works, but I will eventually need to create a Form and render the loading on it.

DownloadFileAsync is work - the file is downloaded, but the events in Register-ObjectEvent themselves do not occur when using any New-Object System.Windows.Forms.* (but work great without them).

Comment: PowerShell is not a great language for what you're looking to accomplish. In this case, your event must execute in a different thread to work properly, and doing so will be quite cumbersome.

Comment: I know, but I want to deal with this particular problem in PS.

Comment: I can share an example with you but the code will not be easy to follow

Comment: I will be grateful. Although it would be enough to simply describe the cause of my problem.

Comment: The problem is that the form has to execute in a different thread than the events otherwise the form will block the thread and the events wont be able to execute until the form is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in comments, PowerShell is not a great language for async programming, the issue is that `.ShowDialog()` blocks the thread and is not allowing your events to execute normally. Solution to this is to register the events in a separated runspace, below is as minimal example of how this can be accomplished (as minimal as I could). I have added a few pointer comments to help you understand the logic, though the code is clearly not easy, as stated before, PowerShell is not a language designed for this, C# would give you  a much easier time.

**Demo:**

[image: demo]

**Code:**

```bash
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$form = [System.Windows.Forms.Form]@{
    Size            = '500, 150'
    FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3d'
}
$btn = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]@{
    Name     = 'MyButton'
    Text     = 'Click Me!'
    Size     = '90, 30'
    Location = '370, 70'
    Anchor   = 'Bottom, Right'
}
$btn.Add_Click({
    # disable the button here to allow a single download at a time
    $this.Enabled = $false
    # hardcoded link here for demo
    $downloader.DownloadFileAsync('https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2301-x64.exe', "$pwd\7Zip.exe")
})
$progress = [System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar]@{
    Name     = 'MyProgressBar'
    Size     = '460, 40'
    Location = '10, 10'
}
$form.Controls.AddRange(($btn, $progress))

# create a WebClient instance
$downloader = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()
# create a new runspace where the Download Events will execute
# this new runspace will have the PSHost hooked so that things like
# `Write-Host`, `Out-Host`, `Write-Warning`, etc. goes straight to the console
# its easier for troubleshooting but not mandatory
$rs = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($Host)
$rs.Open()
# add the `$form` instance to the runspace scope
$rs.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.Set([psvariable]::new('form', $form))

# the code that will initiate the events in the new runspace
$ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({
    $registerObjectEventSplat = @{
        InputObject      = $args[0] # $args[0] = $downloader
        EventName        = 'DownloadProgressChanged'
        SourceIdentifier = 'WebMainDownloadProgressChanged'
        Action           = {
            $progress = $form.Controls.Find('MyProgressBar', $false)[0]
            # for demo, in addition to increment the progress bar,
            # show the percentage to the console
            $eventArgs.ProgressPercentage | Out-Host
            # increment the progress bar
            $progress.Value = $eventArgs.ProgressPercentage
        }
    }
    Register-ObjectEvent @registerObjectEventSplat
    $registerObjectEventSplat['EventName'] = 'DownloadFileCompleted'
    $registerObjectEventSplat['SourceIdentifier'] = 'WebMainDownloadFileCompleted'
    $registerObjectEventSplat['Action'] = {
        [System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter($form)
        # when the download is completed, enable the button
        $form.Controls.Find('MyButton', $false)[0].Enabled = $true
        # and show this to the console
        Write-Host 'Download Completed!'
        [System.Threading.Monitor]::Exit($form)
    }
    Register-ObjectEvent @registerObjectEventSplat
}).AddArgument($downloader)
$ps.Runspace = $rs
$task = $ps.BeginInvoke()
$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: glad this was helpful @Dron. Please ignore `Value`, `Maximum` and `Step` during initializing (I have already removed them from my answer), those values are already the default values so mind as well ignore them. Reg. the other questions: `CreateRunspace($Host)` hooks the PSHost to the new runspace, without it things like `Out-Host` and `Write-Host` wouldn't work. Reg. `AllScope`, this is so the `$form` variable is defined as `$global:form` in the runspace, so that `Register-ObjectEvent` can see it in the `Action` block.

Comment: Wow, just wow. Your code is so beautiful and modern (for example, "[System.Net.WebClient]::new()" instead of "New-Object System.Net.WebClient" and using hash-table). It took me some time to figure it out, but I did it. 

I have a few questions: Why did you set the "Step" in ProgressBar to "0"? What are the benefits of using "CreateRunspace($Host)" instead of "CreateRunspace()"? What are the benefits of using "[System.Management.Automation.ScopedItemOptions]::AllScope" instead of "[System.Management.Automation.ScopedItemOptions]::None"?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment while trying to edit it.

Comment: @Dron added more comments that should answer your questions. If no further questions please consider accepting the answer

Comment: Well, I don’t need the console - I hide it anyway. And with "None" it works the same as with "AllScope", I didn't see any difference.

Comment: By the way, how do you recommend hiding the console window?

Comment: @Dron oh you're right reg. `AllScope` its not needed at all, thats nice (I'll update my answer). I'm also missing `[System.Threading.Monitor]::Enter` to lock the `$form` inside the events will also add it to the edit. reg. hiding the console, I use a shortcut that points to `powershell.exe -File myScript.ps1 -WindowStyle Hidden`

Comment: I think the shortcut is not the best solution. I found this code (and it works):  

Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
'

[Console.Window]::ShowWindow([Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow(), 0)

Comment: @Dron that should be the final version, see update. yes, im aware there are much better ways to launch powershell hidden but the complexity of the code is even higher hehe (also its been a long time since I did something with winforms)

Comment: Santiago Squarzo, can I still disturb you? I came across the issue of passing variables to runspace. I want to make several checkboxes on this form and, when I click on the button, download the required files sequentially. I form an array of the values I need and want to pass it to runspace to process it in `“DownloadFileCompleted”` and start the download again, simultaneously deleting the array element and so loading the required list of files through all of them. But how can we pass there an array with the current value at the time the button was pressed?

Comment: @Dron could you please ask a new question? feel free to reference this one. Hard to help from comments

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77446632/how-to-pass-a-variable-with-the-current-value-to-runspace